# Why is exception thrown here?

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I am preparing for OCA exams and read a lot, so today I saw an a question.
Here is a code:

```
public class Fork {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 1 | args[1].equals("test")) {
        System.out.println("Test case");
    } else {
        System.out.println("production " + args[0]);
    }
  }     
}
```

And the command-line invocation:

```
java Fork live2
```

I thought that answer would be `"production java"`
but the answer is `"An exception is thrown at runtime"`.
Why is that? we are providing values for args right?
Can some one please explain me what is going on?
Thanks!

Comment: args[1] is the problem

Comment: Downvote : Paste the stacktrace, if you want a perfect solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `java Fork live2` there's only 1 command line argument - `live2`.

`args.length == 1 | args[1].equals("test")` is an OR operator that doesn't short circuit, which means both operands are guaranteed to be evaluated (`||` is the OR operator that short circuits and only evaluates the right operand if the left operand is false), so if you supply a single command line argument as you did in `java Fork live2`, `args[1].equals("test")` would still be evaluated and throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

If you change your condition to

```
if (args.length == 1 || args[1].equals("test"))
```

you'll get `Test case` printed, since `args.length == 1` would be true and `args[1].equals("test")` won't be evaluated.

Answer (score 5):

in your if statement:

```
args[1].equals("test")
```

you have only one argument, so args[1] throw array out of bound

Comment: but I am supplying `java Fork live2` as an arguments so length of args should be 3 right?

Comment: And the solution is `if (args.length == 1 || args[0].equals("test")) {`

Comment: @NodirNasirov - java is the executing command, Fork is your class name, arguments starts from live2, so you have only one

Comment: Oh yeeeahh, woow, I thought that java Fork live2 are arguments, but in fact that was complete commands to compile Fork class! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `|`, use `||` and instead of using `args[1].equals("test")` use `args[0].equals("test")`.

In the end it should look something like this:

```
public class Fork {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 1 || args[0].equals("test")) {
        System.out.println("Test case");
    } else {
        System.out.println("production " + args[0]);
    }
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving only one command line argument. So while checking for args[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osxss.png) , you are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception.. If you give two arguments, it will work perfectly..
[image: my output]